# Vim Syntax: Matching a regex in a region to after AND before a keyword

Tags: regex, vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I am looking for a way to code a `.vim` syntax script to match variable names inside a region in a flexible way.

The syntax of the portion of the language I am trying to highlight is like so:

```
Function(arg1, arg2, ... argn);
```

where `args` are of the form `infoo=outfoo`.

Whitespace is ignored in this language.
The code I have so far indicates a region `parens`

```
syn region parens start='(' end=')'
```

Is there a way to match regex expressions using the `syn match 'regex'` command to before and after the `=` character within the `parens` region only?

The problem is more complicated than simply matching all words in the `parens` region because I need to highlight `infoo` and `outfoo`, except when one of them is already something I have implemented syntax highlighting for. Said another way, `infoo` and `outfoo` must be different colors depending on whether they are declared as variable names or are hardcoded into the language.

I have followed [the Vim wiki guide](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Creating_your_own_syntax_files) for most of my efforts, and I am finding it difficult to understand the Vim [documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html). This is my first attempt at writing or editing Vim syntax highlighting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for *syntax containment*; via `contains={group},...`, you tell Vim to parse the arguments *within* the region (else, the region match would prevent other syntax matches in there). Then, you'll define syntax matches for the arguments with the `contained` parameter, so that Vim will only attempt to match those inside (the region).

Here's an example that parses the *in* and *out* parts separately; you can adapt that, and even define another, nested containment, too:

```
syn region parens start='(' end=')' contains=inArgument,outArgument
syn match inArgument "\w\+=\@=" contained
syn match outArgument "=\@<=\w\+" contained
```

Note: The syntax names should better adhere to the {languageName}{SyntaxElementName} style seen in other syntax scripts.